# Add Value to property on ViewController from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I have the following code:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
[tabBarController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"push_display_incomming_call" sender:self];
```

This shows me the ViewController I want to see correctly. But now I want to change the property's value of the ViewController is being Segue before it's shown, I'm Trying the following with no success.

```
incommingCallViewController *mainController = (incommingCallViewController*) tabBarController;
            mainController.name.text = @"Eddwn Paz";
```

This is the stacktrace from xCode Console:

```
2014-07-10 16:46:09.413 mobile-app[9354:60b] -[OptionsTabBarViewController name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17552540
2014-07-10 16:46:09.414 mobile-app[9354:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[OptionsTabBarViewController name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17552540'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that `push_display_incomming_call` segue presents `IncommingCallViewController` view controller as modal. So you should use code:

```
IncommingCallViewController *callVC = 
    (IncommingCallViewController *)tabBarController.presentedViewController;
callVC.name.text = @"Eddwn Paz";
```

**Remarks:**

You receive the error because you try to use `tabBarController` as instance of `incommingCallViewController` while it is instance of `UITabBarController` thus it does not have required `name` property.

Comment: Now I get the following Error  Use of undeclared identifier 'segue'

Comment: I know how to pass values between viewControllers, What I'm trying to do is pass a value to a ViewController from AppDelegate.m

Comment: I see thanks, Can you please explain what happened so others can learn from it also.

Comment: I changed the answer to correct, I appreciate your time for answering.

Comment: I guess that you've assumed that after invoking `perforSeugue...` on `tabBarController` variable it should have a reference to `incommingCallViewController` so you've cast it to the required type. But `tabBarController` variable still point to the same `UITabBarViewController`. At the same time `incommingCallViewController` that was presented with modal segue can be reached using `presentedViewController` property of view controller that presented it.

Comment: Were `incommingCallViewController` presented using push segue then we need to reach it using `tabBarController.navigationController.topViewController` properties.